# All optimal solutions

Tags: solver, simplex

I have a following problem:

If I have some function $aX+bY+cZ+mD+nF$ and I want to maximize it and have some constraints, how can I find ALL solutions for this maximum value of the function?

To sum up: I have a function value (e.g. $100$) and I have one optimal solution ($a,b,c,m,n$ - in my case calculated by Excel solver) but I need the rest of the combination of coefficients that results in the function value ($100$).

Can I calculate that somehow?

Comment: Are your variables continuous or integer ?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Before I answer, did you google "enumerate all optimal solutions" and found links like [this one](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html)?

Comment: To add @Marco Lübbecke mentioned, if you are interested to enumerate all (optimal) feasible solutions, you would like to see [this](https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/COUNTER.php) by SCIP or [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/when-using-docplex-cp-is-it-possible-to-get-all-feasible-solutions) in OR.SE.

Comment: You mentioned the solution being the lower case letters but also said "the rest of the combination[s] of coefficients". Are the lower case letters coefficients and the upper case letters variables, or vice versa?